# Puppeteer bypass recaptcha and fetch all cookies in headless mode

Tags: cookies, puppeteer, headless-browser, cookieyes, cookieserve

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox']});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    try {
        await page.goto('https://www.allabout*****.org', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'}); // 59 second - load - domcontentloaded - networkidle2
        const cookies = await page._client.send('Network.getAllCookies');
        JSON.stringify(cookies, null, 4);

    } catch (e) {

    }
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Tried above code to fetch all cookies but it only takes cookies before accepting captcha. After accepting captcha also, it sets cookies, that are not getting in the cookie list. **How can I escape captcha using puppeteer in headless mode ( headless: true)?**

Tried different independent node modules, puppeteer helpers, nothing worked.

Comment: @tokland - Could you please have a look into this

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your code and realized that you used `{waitUntil: "load"}`. I just replaced that with `{waitUntil: "networkidle2"}` and removed the timeout(still used `headless:true`) and it showed me the `CookieScriptConsent` on cookie list.

Comment: Please see the [screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/GCtDZwx/Screenshot-2019-10-10-at-9-10-41-AM.png), it's not working

Comment: I again tried on try puppeteer. Check out this screenshot https://i.imgur.com/ARLYuu2.png

Comment: But it's not working in my demo server. (exact same code ). Those cookies are getting set after the captcha is verified. So there may be some whitelisting needed from the Cloudflare side, as this is a Cloudflare hosted website. Thanks though

Comment: configured try-puppeteer in localhost - then it's not working ( not bypassing captcha)

Comment: If you do not bypass captcha then you can't get the "CookieScriptConsent" I think.

Comment: I cloned try-puppeteer from GitHub and run the script, then the cookie is not listing. Lost

Comment: @md-abu-taher CAn you have a look into this question